# i am new in action script. trying to split a sentence into words and show them in sprite.and also need which sprite i clicked

Tags: actionscript

I am trying to split a sentence in to words and show them into sprite()

```
var sentence:String = "My name is Subhadip.";
var txt:Array = new Array();
var splittedSentence:Array = sentence.split(" ");

var myArraySprites:Array = new Array();
var myTextImage:Array = new Array();
var div = 40;
for (var i:int = 0; i < splittedSentence.length; i++)
{
    var v = 300 - (div * i);
    //...
    txt[i] = new TextField();
    txt[i].autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    txt[i].text = splittedSentence[i];
    
    var format1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format1.size = 24;
    txt[i].setTextFormat(format1);
    trace(txt[i]);
    
    myArraySprites[i] = new Sprite();
    myArraySprites[i].graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
    myArraySprites[i].buttonMode = true;
    myArraySprites[i].graphics.beginFill( 0xfffffff );
    myArraySprites[i].graphics.drawRect(50, v, 150, div);
    

    myTextImage[i] = new BitmapData(100,v,true,0xffffff);
    myTextImage[i].draw(txt[i]);
    trace(myTextImage[i]);
    
    
    //myArraySprites[i].graphics.beginBitmapFill(myTextImage[i]);
    //myArraySprites[i].graphics.endFill();

    myArraySprites[i].addChild(new Bitmap(myTextImage[i]));
    addChild(myArraySprites[i]);

    myArraySprites[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeThis);


}
function removeThis(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clickTarget:int = myArraySprites.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    trace("Clicked sprite (id): " + clickTarget);
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

trying to split a sentence into words and show them in sprite.and also need which sprite i clicked
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzHUQ.png

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're dealing with screen positions in two different places:

```
myArraySprites[i].graphics.drawRect(50, v, 150, div);
```

and

```
myTextImage[i] = new BitmapData(100,v,true,0xffffff);
```

Think of it in a more object-oriented way. Each `Sprite` instance you want to be clickable is a single object. As such it also holds the main properties e.g. the on-screen position determined by it's `x` and `y` properties.

Each of those sprites have equal width & height, so make this a global property.

```
var wid:Number = 150;
var hei:Number = 40;
```

If we look at your .png, we can see that you want to have a single word centered inside such a sprite. To make things easier, we can use the `.align` property of the `TextFormat` class, set it to `"center"` and make each TextField 150 x 40 by using the `wid` and `hei` properties.

Finally each sprite's vertical screen position is shifted up by `hei` == 40 pixels. So let's determine a start position:

```
var yPos:Number = 300;
```

assign it to a sprite instance:

```
myArraySprites[i].x=50;
myArraySprites[i].y=yPos;
```

and decrement it by `hei` inside the for-loop.

Everything put together:

```
            var yPos:Number = 300;
            var wid:Number = 150;
            var hei:Number = 40;
            var sentence:String = "My name is Subhadip.";
            var txt:TextField = new TextField();
            txt.width = wid;
            txt.height = hei;
            var format1:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format1.size = 24;
            format1.align = "center";
            var splittedSentence:Array = sentence.split(" ");

            var myTextImage:Array = new Array();
            for (var i:int = 0; i<splittedSentence.length; i++)
            {
                txt.text = splittedSentence[i];
                txt.setTextFormat(format1);

                myArraySprites[i] = new Sprite();
                myArraySprites[i].x = 50;
                myArraySprites[i].y = yPos;

                myArraySprites[i].graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
                myArraySprites[i].buttonMode = true;
                myArraySprites[i].graphics.beginFill(0xfffffff);
                myArraySprites[i].graphics.drawRect(0, 0, wid, hei);

                myTextImage[i] = new BitmapData(wid, hei, true, 0xffffff);
                myTextImage[i].draw(txt);

                myArraySprites[i].addChild(new Bitmap(myTextImage[i]));
                addChild(myArraySprites[i]);

                myArraySprites[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeThis);

                yPos -= hei;
            }
```